# How do I programmaticaly set an image on glassmapped item

Tags: glass-mapper

So I have a glassMapped item with an image.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = TemplateIdConstants.NationalChain, EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public interface IChain : IGlassBase
{
    [SitecoreField("Logo")]
    Image Logo { get; set; }
}
```

Witch I then try to set:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
using (var db = new SitecoreContext(Sitecore.Context.Database))
{
    var item = db.Create<IChain, IGlassBase>(parent, model.Name);
    item.Logo = new Image { MediaId = image.ID.ToGuid() };
    db.Save(item);
}
```

This does not work, so I'm looking for the correct way to do this.

Edit, I found one way that works..although I'm not happy with it. I added the following to the interface:

```
[SitecoreField("Logo")]
string LogoString { get; set; }
```

I then set the raw value like this:

```
item.LogoString = "<image mediaid=\"{" + image.ID.ToGuid() + "}\" />";
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

The following gives a strange result. Image is set while Logo is not set.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = TemplateIdConstants.NationalChain, EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public interface IChain : IGlassBase
{
  [SitecoreField("Logo")]
  Image Logo { get; set; }
  [SitecoreField("Image")]
  Image Image { get; set; }
}
  item.Image = new Image { MediaId = image.ID.ToGuid() };
  item.Logo = new Image { MediaId = image.ID.ToGuid() };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Any exception? Or nothing happens?

Comment: Nothing happens, other fields are saved ok, just not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure with your GlassMapper version, but anyway check **SecurityDisabler**, **SitecoreType** attribute (provide error details to get answer faster).

Working solution with class (instead of interface)

Model:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{[your template ID]}"]
public class ChildItem
{
    [SitecoreField("Image")]
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }

    [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Url)]
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Saving:

```
 using (new SecurityDisabler())
 {
    using (var service = new SitecoreService("master"))
    {
        var childItem = new ChildItem
        {
          Name = "child";
          Image = new Image {MediaId = new Guid("{[your media ID]}")};
        };
        service.Create(parentItem, childItem);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Your code does exactly the same as mine, except you'r code wont work since we are using interfaces and not classes.

Comment: Where are SecurityDisabler, SitecoreType attribute, SitecoreService in your code?

Comment: I'm using SitecoreContext instead of Service, the other two I didn't put into the example code, also MediaId is a Guid not a text string

Comment: Ive added disabler and type so the example is complete

Comment: BTW: SitecoreContext inherits from AbstractSitecoreContext which inherits from SitecoreService.

Comment: What glassmapper version do you use?  
item.Logo = new Image { MediaId = image.ID.Guid}; was always worked with Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField and existing image.ID

Comment: <package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc" version="4.5.0.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core" version="4.5.0.4" targetFramework="net472" />

Comment: Seems like glassmapper only works if the field is actually named Image. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Does mapping work when you try to retrieve existing item image with name Logo with GetItem<>? Or if it works with name "Image", may be you have any other field "Logo"?

Comment: The logo field works fine for retrieval, and as I said, I can even set it via the LogoString hack and read it back in the "logo" field on refresh. But it won't save to db when I set it with = new Image(). There is only one "logo" defined on the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92393/discussion-between-x3mxray-and-devzero).